# If $(v_n)_n$ is a Hilbert basis for $H$ over $\mathbb{C}$, can you turn $(\mathrm{Re}(v_n), \mathrm{Im}(v_n))_n$ also to a Hilbert basis for $H$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

(**Question:**) Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space over the field $\mathbb{C}$ and that $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a Hilbert basis for it, that is a sequence of orthonormal vectors whose span is dense in $H$. I am wondering whether we can turn the sequence of real and imaginary parts of every $v_n$ also to a Hilbert basis for $H$, that is can we turn $(\mathrm{Re}(v_n), \mathrm{Im}(v_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ to an orthonormal sequence whose span is also dense in $H$? If you are wondering that the real and imaginary parts for $v_n$s mean, suppose for example that $H$ is some $L^2$ (or $l^2$) space over the field $\mathbb{C}$ so that each $v_n$ is a priori a complex valued function satisfying $v_n(x) = \mathrm{Re}(v_n(x)) + i\mathrm{Im}(v_n(x)) = r_n(x) + ic_n(x)$ for some real-valued functions $r_n, c_n$.

(**Motivation:**) We know from basic Fourier theory that the functions $$e_n(x) = \exp(2\pi i n x/(b-a))$$
form an orthonormal basis for the space $L^2([a,b];\mathbb{C})$. Take e.g. for $a = -\pi, b = \pi$. As $L^1([a,b];\mathbb{C})\subset L^2([a,b];\mathbb{C})$, we can represent any $f\in L^1([-\pi,\pi];\mathbb{C})$ as
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \alpha_ne_n(x), \alpha_n\in\mathbb{C}$$

where $\alpha_n = \hat{f}(k)$. By writing $$\alpha_n = a_n + b_ni$$ with $a_n,b_n\in\mathbb{R}$, we can further write

$$\alpha_ne_n(x) = (a_n + b_ni)\cos(xn) + (a_ni - b_n)\sin(xn)$$

showing that $f$ is the sum over some real valued functions with complex coefficients. In the case of such $L^2$ space over a symmetric interval, sine and cosine have good orthogonality properties, that with $L^2$ normalization constants $s_n, t_n$, the sequence $(s_n\sin(xn), t_n\cos(xn))_{n=1}^\infty$ is an orthonormal sequence spanning $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$.

For a general such $L^2$ish space where we can meaningfully talk about the real and imaginary parts of the basic vectors, say, $(v_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, I think that it might not be true that immediately that elements of the sequence $(\mathrm{Re}(v_n), \mathrm{Im}(v_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ are orthogonal to one another. **Note:** I am saying *I think*, because I don't know how to construct a counter example. But in any case, provided that every elements of our general Hilbert space $f\in H$ can be written as

$$f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_nv_n, \alpha_n\in\mathbb{C}$$

we may again decompose the sum to see that

$$f = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n + b_ni)\mathrm{Re}(v_n) + (a_ni - b_n)\mathrm{Im}(v_n)$$

where $\mathrm{Re}(v_n)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(v_n)$ are real-valued. One idea to turn any finite set $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ of possibly linearly dependent vectors $w_k$ to a new orthonormal set $\{u_1,\dots,u_j\}$, where $j\leq n$, such that the span of $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ equals the span of $\{u_1,\dots,u_j\}$, is to use the [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). Specifically, we are using Gram-Schmidt in such a way that we discard any zero elements that might occur when we subtract projections (to avoid division by zero), and instead move to the next element in our list of unprocessed vectors $w_l$.

(**Problem(s):**) Relabel the sequence $(\mathrm{Re}(v_n), \mathrm{Im}(v_n))_{n=1}^\infty$ to $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. When trying to orthonormalize the sequence $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, I ran into the difficulty of what to do if some $w_k$ depends linearly on arbitrarily many $w_l$s with $l > k$. To be more precise, given a new vector $w_k$ that is linearly dependent on other members of $(w_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, I am not sure how I can argue that

$$w_k = \sum_{j\in \mathcal{I}}\alpha_jw_j$$

for a finite index set $\mathcal{I}$. But even if such finiteness property would hold, I am not really sure what we should do if the $w_k$ elements would satisfy e.g. the property that for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ there is a non-empty index set $\mathcal{I}(k)$ such that $w_k$ is in the linear span of the elements $w_l$ with $l\in\mathcal{I}(k)$ and $l >k$. In the finite dimensional case we don't have this sort of a problem, since there is an element in an ordered version of the set $\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$. Is there any way to use G-S in this kind of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space?

Comment: Your question makes no sense in a *general* Hilbert space, where vectors don't have real and imaginary parts. I think you should either reformulate it in some of your examples of Hilbert spaces where it makes sense, or enrich your general Hilbert space with abstract operators $\mathrm{Re,Im}$ satisfying some special properties mimicking those of the usual operators of your examples.

Comment: Note that in your example, the imaginary part of $e_0$
 is $0$. Even worse: if you start with $(v_n)=$ $(s_n\sin(xn), t_n\cos(xn))_{n=1}^\infty$, orthonormal sequence spanning $L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, then the real part of *each* of its vectors is itself and its imaginary part is $0$. The key point with $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb Z}$ was that it is closed under conjugation.

Comment: ...(follow up) and that all its vectors except $e_0$ have their real and imaginary parts both $\ne0$.

Comment: The only generalization I can see of the very special case of your example with Fourier is that if $u,v$ are two vectors of some Hilbert basis of a Hilbert space, then $a:=\frac{u+v}2,b:=\frac{u-v}{2i}$ are still orthogonal to eachother and to the other vectors of the Hilbert basis, so that (after rescaling) they can replace $u,v$ in the Hilbert basis, provided $a,b$ were both nonzero.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the feedback! The issue you have raised did not occur to me, since I was too concentrated on trying to prove my question, rather than understand does it make sense. I will post later a question with more appropriate structure.

Regarding the your second comment, why would it be a problem that some, or all, basic vectors have their real or imaginary (not both!) parts equal to zero? My question boils down to: if $H$ has Re and Im parts of its elements and it has a Hilbert basis, can we make a new Hilbert basis out of the Re and Im parts of the old basis? And if so, how?

Comment: The problem (for me) was only that you intended to include both the real and imaginary parts of your $v_n$s into your new Hilbert basis, instead of discarding one of them if it happens to be $0$. As for your final question (after "boils down to"), I think I answered it in my last comment (provided your Hilbert basis is closed under conjugation, which seems a necessary condition). (This condition makes sense: once you have a notion of real and imaginary part of a vector, you can define its conjugate.)

Comment: @AnneBauval I think a final touch will make the entire post clearer for other readers: 1.) When I said "can we turn $(Re(v_n), Im(v_n))_n$ to an ONB", I envisioned that we i.) discard possible zero elements, ii.) discard possible linearly dependent elements, iii.) normalize as necessary, like when $H$ is finite-dimensional (my note on G-S). But this is only a semantic note. 2.) I think your latest suggestion is part of a solution: it's just that your $a,b$ might not be real-valued (compared to what was attempted) so the proposed construction is IMO a bit different. But still a good suggestion!

Comment: 2) The aim of my suggestion was to remedy the problem (raised in my first comment) that in an arbitrary Hilbert space, the notions of "real-valued" and "real and imaginary part" don't exist. As I said, it is a generalization of your special case where they do. 1) Replacing $u,v$ (in the Hilbert basis) by $\frac{u+v}2,\frac{u-v}{2i}$ whenever both are $\ne0$ but only in this case (and doing this simultaneously for as many pairs $(u,v)$ as you want) frees you from discarding zero or dependent elements: there won't be any.